# Using Iso639 comparison in Rails Active Record Json field filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to search if there are any records which has the specific language . Language is stored in short forms, for example : 'en-US' and I want to search it against plain text format, for example : "English". The values are stored as json.

```
  def rule_is
      filtered_visitor_ids = Insights::Visit.where(
        "visitor_id IN (?) AND lower(insights_visits.context#>>'{browser, language}')) = lower(?)", visitors.pluck(:id), visitor_attribute_value).distinct.pluck(:visitor_id)
      visitors.where(id: filtered_visitor_ids)
    end
```

Example:

visitor_attribute_value is "English" and I want to search it against "en-US" . How can I do this using Iso639?

Comment: Why `en-US`? Why not `en-GB`, `en-AU`, or just `en-`? I think you will need to define a mapping which very specific code you want to use when the input is very unspecific and general.

Comment: @spickermann I just specified en-US as an example . It can be any language.

Comment: @spickermann I want to convert the string like "English" to ISO639 format like "en-US" and compare.

Comment: Or I want to convert the "en-US" in the db back to string like "English" and compare it against the visitor_attribute_value @spickermann

Answer (score 0):

[i18n_data](https://github.com/grosser/i18n_data) can help you.

```rb
require 'i18n_data'

I18nData.language_code('English') # EN
I18nData.languages('en') # List of countries
```

Or if you want to have more control you can use the [raw files](https://github.com/grosser/i18n_data/tree/master/cache/file_data_provider) with the information, or even from the [source](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code_tables/download_tables#Complete%20Code%20Tables) and parse them yourself.

Comment: Will it work with "en-US", "en-AU" etc ?

Comment: You can get a list of those codes in [here](http://www.sean-crist.com/professional/pages/language_region_codes/language_region_codes_crist_201805.txt) there may be better ones out there.
You don't need to treat the whole "en-AU" as an entity, first part is the language code and second one the country code. [countries](https://github.com/countries/countries) gem can also help you with the task.